# How can one travel between terminals at Noi Bai (Hanoi) airport?

Tags: transit, airports, vietnam, hanoi, han

So I will be arriving on an internal flight from Da Nang to Hanoi. My understanding is this is likely to arrive at the old terminal, while my onward international flight will be from the new terminal. How can one get between the two? It didn't look like there was any sensible way to walk it when I arrived before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a free shuttle bus between the two terminals. In addition, there are golf carts standing by at some cost.

Details can be found [on the Vietnam airports website](http://en.vietnamairport.vn/page/118/hot-events/t2-passenger-terminal-guidance), which says:

> Passengers can use shuttle bus (free of charge for transit passengers) to transport between T1 and T2 terminal.
>
> - Time of operation: From 06h00 to 24h00 (local time);
> - Frequency: From 10 to 15 minutes/ 01 respective vehicle.
> - Maintaining other means of transportation (tram, public bus)

The signs at the actual site indicate that frequency is 10 minutes during the day time and 20 minutes in the early morning/late evening. The shuttle bus is a small coach with space underneath for suitcases. Coming from T1 arrivals, turn right and walk up to the end of the terminal for the collection point. There are LED signs indicating the way.

Comment: How about if you need to transfer outside the bus operation hours? What are the options?

Comment: @aljof  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/111005/101