# How to get from Hanoi International Airport Terminal 2 to Domestic 1 at 5 am?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, taxis, hanoi

The title says it all: the shuttle bus seems to start at 6 am but I need transport between terminals at 5 am. Can you take a taxi, and if so how much?

Answer (score 3):

It's less than a half a km. It's easier to just follow the signs and walk it. It's a small airport.

I doubt any taxi will take you as they wait a long time for customers and taxis are very cheap in Hanoi, unless of course you agree to say 100,000 VND or something - money talks. It's a little unfair to expect meter usage in my opinion regardless of the "law".

Comment: Just to update, I did this last week in the other direction so fresher memory this time, taxis on meter are 14k-20k (17k was showing on meter but the other direction may be a little longer), i gave the guy 40k - everyone is happy, the journey took ~2mins as I couldn't be bother with a large suitcase. To walk it from international to domestic, turn left out the terminal, walk along in the face of traffic along the highway 400m and turn left again into the domestic carpark. It's may be dark so just get a taxi.